# Changing property values from within the component in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm wondering how I'd go about dynamically editing a component property from within the component. Code might help you get a bit more clarity on what I'm trying to do.

Templates/boards.hbs

```
<div>
  {{board-component title='Title that wants to be dynamic'}}
</div>
```

Components/board-component.hbs

```
{{#if isEditing}}

  <div>
    <input type="text" value={{title}}>
  </div>

{{else}}

  <div>
    {{title}}
  </div>

{{/if}}
```

Am I right in saying that standard behaviour would have the value I specify in the input reflect as the title, but due to the fact that I've declared the value in the template it reverts back to this declared value?

How can I get around this?

Comment: .You are not using input helper.so it's not two way binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value={{title}}>
```

It means, board-component `title` property will get values from boards.hbs. and initially, this will be displayed in the input. but changing input value will not reflect it in `title` property of the components.

But if you used input helper like below,

```
{{input type="text" value=title}}
```

It is two way binding between input value and title property. so whenever you change value from input that will reflect in components.

So answer to your question, use input helper.

```
{{input type="text" value=title}}
```